# How do work the Dell Studio 1537's remote control with infrared receiver port IT8512 CIR

Tags: 10.10, hardware, dell, lirc, remote-control

I use Ubuntu 10.10. Please Can someone help me? the remote control is the only component that does not work with Ubuntu.

@Martin many thanks for your answer and excuse me for the delay.

i have test the Lirc driver ITE8709, but it not working properly. I add my result with the lirc in official repository.

```
lino@lino-Studio-1537:~$ lsmod | grep -i lirc
lirc_ite8709            6328  0 
lirc_dev               11209  1 lirc_ite8709

lino@lino-Studio-1537:~$ dmesg | grep -i lirc
[   17.698130] lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 249 
[   17.740420] lirc_ite8709: module is from the staging directory, the quality is    unknown, you have been warned.

lino@lino-Studio-1537:~$ sudo mode2 -d /dev/lirc0
mode2: could not get file information for /dev/lirc0
mode2: default_init(): No such file or directory
```

And the command cat /proc/ioports | grep -i lirc produces nothing.

Long time ago i have read end test [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8716710#post8716710) in Ubuntu forum and I had more results. I've downloaded the file for dell 1535 and all commands entered above give me positive results. Except irw that not working.

i think that the problem is in the driver ITE8709. I hope that someone can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The program you need is called lirc supports the remote control, looking into it it seems the driver is certainly supported but your dell model doesn't yet have a configuration file to map the buttons to actions.

In order to get this working we need a sys-admin or programmer to take a look at your computer while your pressing the keys to figure it out and write the configuration. The best part is that once it's written everyone else who has the same remote control should have a better time of using it.

Notes for anyone who wants to do this work: It looks like ITE8709 is the driver for IT8512 (at least in the code).

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Studio 1737 and also have a non-working remote on Ubuntu, maybe you can get lirc developers to look at it.

This is a thread I started a while ago: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lirc/forums/forum/16772/topic/3407688